# Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface

Tags: java, spring, database, configuration

Good afternoon

Please help me with this problem

Here's the message I get

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource: Class
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider
> does not implement the requested interface
> jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

config:

```
package ru.spring.rest.Config;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ru.spring.rest")
public class DbConfig {

    @Resource
    Environment env;

    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME="db.driver-class-name";
    private static final String URL="db.url";
    private static final String USERNAME="db.username";
    private static final String PASSWORD="db.password";


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public HikariDataSource getDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty(URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty(USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean("entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("name");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("ru.spring.rest.Entities");
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
package ru.spring.rest.Repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.spring.rest.Entities.UserEntity;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, String> {
    List<UserEntity> getAll();
}
```

Entity:

```
package ru.spring.rest.Entities;


import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(schema = "rest", name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "second_name")
    private String secondName;

    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    private String patronymic;

    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;


    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

build gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'my.test.rest'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.6'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.9.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.6.9.Final'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have already tried changing dependency versions and adding properties to hibernateProperties

Remove the org.hibernate dependencies helped, but an error has appear:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource null

StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at ru.spring.rest.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.contributeTypes(PostgreSQLDialect.java:1249) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize PostgreSQLPGObjectJdbcType
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.<clinit>(PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.postgresql.util.PGInterval.getWholeSeconds()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2728) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.<clinit>(PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Remove the `org.hibernate` dependencies, those are already part of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and interfere with the correct version management.